# Как взять из БД sqlite3 взять значение, выполнить действие, потом взять следующее значение - действие и т.д

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Подскажите как взять из БД созданной с помощью sqlite3 значение id пользователя и соответствующее ему значение api токена, далее проделать определенную операцию, потом взять следующее значение

Для примера:

```
              id  |  api
          121212  |  xyz
          131313. |  zyx 

в БД есть столбец id и api
```

Код который использовал ранее, но здесь лишнее chat_id, оно не нужно для кода который хочу сейчас:

```
user_id = sqlite3.connect('id_plus_api.db')
cursor = user_id.cursor()
chat_id = message.chat.id
exists = cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM id_api WHERE id = ?", [chat_id]).fetchone()
```

Нужно примерно следующее:

```
try:
    users_id = sqlite3.connect('id_plus_api.db')
    cursor = users_id.cursor()
    user_id = cursor.execute('''SELECT id FROM id_api #сначала взять первый id
    user_api = custom.executr('''SELECT api FROM id_api #сначала взять первый api
    def api_zapros(user_id, user_api):
        parameters ={
                'key' : str(api)
        }
        r.requests(url, params=parameters).json()
        bot.send_message(#отправить пользователю по id данные r)
    api_zapros (user_id, user_api)
    time.sleep(60) # перед повторным запросом подождать минуту, а далее взять вторую строку со вторым значением id и api и повторить цикл и т.д. пока не переберем все строки в БД
except:
    pass
```

Comment: rows = cursor.fetchall()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказка от @Виктор уже есть, ну напишу чуть подробнее:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id, api FROM id_api')
for user_id, user_api in cursor.fetchall():
    api_zapros(user_id, user_api)
    time.sleep(60)
```